# Can Kotlin Exposed be used from Java code

Tags: kotlin-exposed

I know that you in general can call Kotlin code from Java, but is this something worth doing when doing Exposed? Or is it's API too tied to the idomatic way of coding Kotlin.

Has any one experience with using Kotlin Exposed from Java code? And does it play well?

Comment: There are some interop problems atm. Table overrides a method throwing an exception and the .class reports this as Void return type: Error:(8, 14) java: modifyStatement() in org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table cannot implement modifyStatement() in org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.DdlAware
  return type java.lang.Void is not compatible with java.util.List<java.lang.String>
Another problem is the use of 'new' as method name

Comment: Is there any update on this issue?